# What are the list of math books one must complete before entering into a Ph.D.?

Tags: career-development

I am interested to know what books one should complete before entering their Ph.D. in mathematics? What topics I should have a strong grip on in order to feel eligible for entering into a Ph.D.

One of my seniors said I must complete Baby Rudin, Munkres's Topology, Conway's Complex Analysis.

I want a complete list of such topics and books. This will help me prepare for my PhD.

Comment: This really depends on the school, program and their requirements and those change over time.

Comment: You dont have to "complete" any of those listed books.

Comment: I'm a second year math Ph.D grad student and I can confidently say I've never had to finish a math book all the way through.

Comment: Topics would be Real Analysis and Abstract Algebra (at the absolute minimum). As for books, there is no standard list. I think, your question is mostly a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280974/what-is-the-expected-mathematical-repertoire-of-a-ph-d-program-applicant-in-the?rq=1).

Comment: @MichaelMorrow: What are the topics you had a good grip on before entering your Ph.D.?

Comment: I got a B.S. in math, took undergrad classes in abstract algebra and analysis. Those are the main two. As long as you're comfortable with those subjects and can write decent proofs, I'd say you'll be fine.

Comment: There isn't really any such list. I've never finished reading a math book.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: What topics did you study before your Ph.D?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the expected mathematical repertoire of a Ph.D. program applicant in the US?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280974/what-is-the-expected-mathematical-repertoire-of-a-ph-d-program-applicant-in-the)

Comment: Lots of stuff - Munkres, Rudin, and Artin's *Algebra* were probably the most important. (But I never finished any of them, as I said.)

Answer (score 1):

Just look at what ppl who got a Ph.D. got to read and found to be insightful instead of asking this. The math sorcerer has book recommendations like this.